# How to resolve this error in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, interface

```
Payfort\Fort\Block\Payment\Redirect
Incorrect dependency in class Payfort\Fort\Block\Payment\Redirect in /var/www/magento/app/code/Payfort/Fort/Block/Payment/Redirect.php
\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface already exists in context object
```

How to solve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use logger as following.

```
$logger = $context->getLogger();
```

And remove **\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface** from your constructor.

This is because context object already contains logger interface.